# StrictUnion that allows extra properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given this `StrictUnion` generic:

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends T? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, undefined>> : never;
export type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Working = StrictUnion<(
  { id: number } | 
  { uuid: string } | 
  { memberId: number } | 
  { memberUuid: string } | 
  { member: Member } | 
  { organizationId: number, contactId: number })
>

const a: Working = { id: 1 }
const b: Working = { uuid: '123456' }
const c: Working = { organizationId: 1, contactId: 1 }
const d: Working = { organizationId: 1 }
const e: Working = { id: 1, organizationId: 1, contactId: 1 } // I would like this to work
const f: Working = { }
```

I'd like `StrictUnion` here to allow "extra" properties. Meaning this should work:

```
{ id: 1, organizationId: 1, contactId: 1 }
```

I'm looking for matches, to match at least one of the unions, but also allow for extra properties, meaning you wouldn't be able to just pass `organizationId` because it needs `contactId` but you would be able to pass just `id` but not `empty` `{}`.

The issue if you use a regular union is this, if there is a way to use a regular union and solve these issues I would accept that as a solution.

[image]

```
  async member(props: (
    { id: number } | 
    { uuid: string } | 
    { memberId: number } | 
    { memberUuid: string } | 
    { member: Member } | 
    { organizationId: number, contactId: number })
  ) {
    const member = await (async () => { 
      if (props.member) return member
      if (props.id) return this.memberRepository.readOneByIdOrFail(props.id)
      if (props.memberId) return this.memberRepository.readOneByIdOrFail(props.memberId)
      if (props.uuid) return this.memberRepository.readOneByUuidOrFail(props.uuid)
      if (props.memberUuid) return this.memberRepository.readOneByUuidOrFail(props.memberUuid)
      if (props.organizationId && props.contactId) return this.memberService.readByUnique(props)
      throw new Error(`unable to ${MemberService.name}.member`)
    })()
    return { member }
  }
```

More thoughts:

```
type Requirements = (
  { id: number } | 
  { uuid: string } | 
  { memberId: number } | 
  { memberUuid: string } | 
  { member: Member } | 
  { organizationId: number, contactId: number }
)

✅ Should be valid
❌ Should not be valid

const a: Requirements = { id: 1 } ✅
const b: Requirements = { uuid: '123456' } ✅
const c: Requirements = { id: null, uuid: null } ✅ (will throw, but valid)
const d: Requirements = { uuid: '123456', contactId: 1 } ✅
const e: Requirements = { organizationId: 1, contactId: 1 } ✅
const f: Requirements = { uuid: '12345', organizationId: 1, contactId: 1 } ✅
const g: Requirements = { uuid: null, organizationId: 1, contactId: 1 } ✅
const h: Requirements = { organizationId: 1 } ❌
const i: Requirements = { id: 1, organizationId: undefined } ✅
const j: Requirements = { } ❌
```

I like what `AtLeastOne` does:

```
type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U]
```

Which prevents an empty object {}

```
AtLeastOne<{
    id: number,
    uuid: string,
    memberId: number,
    memberUuid: string,
    member: Member,
    organizationId: number,
    contactId: number
}>
```

I just want `organizationId` or `contactId` to be invalid alone, because they are a pair.

Here's some ideas of names for what I want `PartialPairs` or `AtLeastOnePair`:

```
PartialPairs<
  { id: number } | 
  { uuid: string } | 
  { memberId: number } | 
  { memberUuid: string } | 
  { member: Member } | 
  { organizationId: number, contactId: number }
>

AtLeastOne<{
  { id: number } | 
  { uuid: string } | 
  { memberId: number } | 
  { memberUuid: string } | 
  { member: Member } | 
  { organizationId: number, contactId: number }
}>
```

Comment: Can you just use a regular union? It shouldn't allow `{ organizationId: 1} by itself either.

Comment: @ProdigySim added context on reason why a regular union does not work.

Comment: @ThomasReggi If `id` is valid in one constituent of the union why not just add it, even if just as optional (`{ organizationId: number, contactId: number, id?: number }`). If you want to allow members from any member constituent why not use a regular union ? It is not clear to me from the code above if yo can mix and match `id` from one contituent into another why `StrictUnion` is necessary at all..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes I agree I am beginning to understand the complexity of what I want. 1) I don't want empty to work, 2) I want specific pairs to  be required (even if they are null or undefined). I have `type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U]` but that doesn't work for pairs. 3) I do want extra `undefined` or `null` to work as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir this question is out of control open to suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688188/what-is-the-proper-way-to-type-this-function

Comment: I really don't understand why a regular union doesn't work here.  Maybe try a regular union and *remove* code and words from this question that are not relevant.  "strict union allowing extra properties" seems like a contradiction to me.

Comment: @jcalz, for the regular union I can't conditionally pick any of the properties because not all properties are guaranteed to be apart of any specific union. See the screenshot above.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwNIRAZwDwBUB8UAvFLlBAB7ARwAmmpUA-FANYZIBmjAXFHBABuEAE4BuALAAoUJCgBlYCIQBjYPGRwAEhAA2kEXgA0pAIK7dhEmUrU6DMizIAyKAAUAhiOAIPu7ABKECpIIrTYAKIUKroArrQQ2Boo6Fh45pYm7CBcpPgmsXQQnAgCtPiEfALC4tKUYKHAULLQispqyXB4VgpKquqIKDr6osZ50i1QALIQALYARqLE-LELomJQ0pyFappQs3OLIgAUAPpgIkhgmHzH0lAPUADeUAi0VatHUAC+UAA+90eL1isTefEwfTgAHMfv9AQ8Xgc1iIAJLvFbI2EAqSPZ77Q6iGCg9EQ5TQrHwvFIo58GaY37Y3EvUJQjyIABeHh8KDRH2RJhCcGAHjUvIxX2+AEppJLnpTBRCoBcrjdeu0BppsC1cudLtcerqVZIcY9ldcAHTU9aUs2Yc1vY2422Wgmo2iO016u0gh02r0u5FE30mh7OllshCc7lwNFQZyuZ2C4Wi93Sb7SIA)?

Comment: You want the function to accept a regular union and widen to the strict union in the function.  Or do any of the other things people do when picking from a union (use an `in` type guard, type assertions, etc)