# What is the proper way to type composite function?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create this composite function and I'd like to type this `member` function you can see it checks props and will return a `member` based on which props were passed in.

What is the best way to type this function?

```
async function member(props: any) {
  const member = await (async () => { 
    if (props.member) return member
    if (props.id) return this.memberRepository.readOneByIdOrFail(props.id)
    if (props.memberId) return this.memberRepository.readOneByIdOrFail(props.memberId)
    if (props.uuid) return this.memberRepository.readOneByUuidOrFail(props.uuid)
    if (props.memberUuid) return this.memberRepository.readOneByUuidOrFail(props.memberUuid)
    if (props.organizationId && props.contactId) return this.memberService.readByUnique(props)
    throw new Error(`unable to ${MemberService.name}.member`)
  })()
  return { member }
}

member({ id: 1, uuid: '123456' })
member({ id: undefined, uuid: '123456' })
member({ uuid: undefined, organizationId: 1, contactId: 1 })
```

Comment: Question seems a bit more suited to [codereview.se]. I'm not sure there is a *best* way to write it but you might look into *improving* what you have.

Comment: Please consider editing the code in this question to constitute a [mcve] as described by [ask].  Ideally the code could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate your issue.